# How to handle passwords in config/properties files

Tags: java, docker, spring-boot

We have a shared code base between different teams. Is there any kind of best practice of storing admin credentials in a spring properties file? I don't want anyone to see the username or password. We are using docker and aware I can use docker secrets but I don't want to tie passwords to docker. I want to access the passwords even if we're not using docker.

Comment: I personally don't say no point in adding an encrypted version of your properties to your SCM. As long as there is only a limited number of secrets it makes no difference if you share the encryption key or the password. I would remove the password from the properties and implement a properties override mechanism. Spring boot already offers the possibility to merge properties from different locations. Add the password properties to your local environment config and you're done.

Answer (score 3):

You can try jasypt to overcome this.

Link: http://www.jasypt.org/

Answer (score 1):

One of the best solutions I know is Blackbox https://github.com/StackExchange/blackbox (via stackexchange ;)

Answer (score 1):

**Simple Approach**: Use environment variables instead of putting sensitive values inside your application.properties file.

**Advanced Approach**: [Vault.](https://www.vaultproject.io/) Check out the [Spring Cloud Vault](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-vault/) project for more details on how to leverage Vault with Spring applications.

Answer (score 0):

Encrypt the `application.properties` file, then track it with `git`.

Then Simply ingore the decrypted `application.properties`.

Answer (score 0):

In **Docker Swarm** use **secrets**. In a normal Docker daemon use Environment Variables or `env_file`